# Retirar nome sublinhado e colocar tag <b></b>

Tags: php, css

preciso de uma ajuda de vocês

Tenho um site de jogo, e em uma pagina do meu site, mostra as informações de um personagem , quando eu passo o mouse por cima daquela espada, ele me trás os atributos que ela possui.

No nome Magic Sword, pode-se perceber que o nome está Sublinhado, eu gostaria que alguem me ajuda-se a remover este sublinhado do nome **Magic sword**. 
Irei postar os arquivos que utilizo para esta função.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**characters.php COMPLETO**
https://jsfiddle.net/f50zwvt4/

**characters.php**

```
        // EQSHOWER
include 'eqs/config.php';
include 'eqs/functions.php';

$query=mysql_query("SELECT pid,itemtype FROM `player_items` WHERE `player_id`= ".$player->getId()." AND `pid`<=10");
if($query){
    while ($result=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $item[$result['pid']]['img']="<img src='images/items/".$result['itemtype'].".gif' />";
        $item[$result['pid']]['id']=$result['itemtype'];
        $class[$result['pid']]="a0-".$result['pid'];
    }
    $EQShower=new EQShower;

    for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
    {
        $num_attr=0;
        unset($val);$val=array();

        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `s_items` INNER JOIN `s_attributes` ON s_items.itemid=s_attributes.item_id WHERE s_items.itemid=".$item[$i]['id']);
        if($query)$result=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

        $val[0]=ucfirst($result['name']);
        $val[1]=$result['descr'];
        $val[2]=$result['armor'];
        $val[3]=$result['weight'];
        $val[4]=$result['containerSize'];
        $val[5]=$result['attack'];
        $val[6]=$result['speed'];
        $val[13]=$result['extraDef'];
        $val[7]=$result['defense'];
        $val[8]=$result['elementFire'];
        $val[9]=$result['elementIce'];
        $val[10]=$result['elementEarth'];
        $val[11]=$result['elementEnergy'];
        $val[12]=$result['range'];
        $val[14]=$result['skillShield'];
        $val[15]=$result['magicLevelPoints'];
        $val[16]=$result['absorbPercentall'];
        $val[17]=$result['charges'];
        $val[18]=$result['skillDist'];
        $val[19]=$result['absorbPercentFire'];
        $val[20]=$result['absorbPercentEarth'];
        $val[21]=$result['absorbPercentIce'];
        $val[22]=$result['absorbPercentEnergy'];
        $val[23]=$result['absorbPercentDeath'];
        $val[24]=$result['absorbPercentHoly'];
        $val[25]=$result['absorbPercentPhysical'];
        $val[26]=$result['skillAxe'];
        $val[27]=$result['skillClub'];
        $val[28]=$result['skillSword'];
        $val[29]=$result['duration'];
        $val[30]=$result['skillFist'];
        $val[31]=$result['absorbPercentManaDrain'];
        $val[32]=$result['absorbPercentLifeDrain'];
        $val[33]=$result['preventDrop'];
        $val[34]=$result['hitChance'];
        $val[35]=$result['shootType'];

        foreach($val as $attribute)
        {
            if(!empty($attribute))$num_attr++;
        }

        $tooltip[$i]=$EQShower->item_info($val,$num_attr);

        if(empty($item[$i])){
        $class[$i]="a".$i;
        $tooltip[$i]="<font class=\'attr\'><b>Empty item slot.</b></font>";
        }
    }

}
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @author Soulreaper
 * @copyright 2010
 * SoulAAC EQShower Config
 */
 //Database connection info.
 $host="127.0.0.1"; // Host name 
 $username="root"; // Mysql username 
 $password="kkkk"; // Mysql password 
 $db_name="kkkk"; // Database name 

 //Set the float type of the tooltip bars.
 //Center -> Text aligns in  the center of the tooltip
 //Left -> Text aligns left in the tooltip
 //Right -> Text aligns right in the tooltip
 $config['align']='left';

 //Colors of the grades always # infront
 //of the hexadecimal value.
 $config['colors']['normal']="#ff8f00";
 $config['colors']['rare']="#ff8f00";
 $config['colors']['epic']="#ff8f00";
 $config['colors']['legendary']="#ff8f00";
 //Classes of the grades
 $config['class']['normal']="norm";
 $config['class']['rare']="rare";
 $config['class']['epic']="epic";
 $config['class']['legendary']="lege";

 //Amount Of Attributes Determine Grade.

 // Installer config don't change any 
 //unless you know what you're doing
 $files[0]='s_items.sql';
 $files[1]='s_attributes.sql';

 //Exceptions array CASE SENSITIVE
 //First letter must be a capital, further no capitals
 //And no capitals in the grades either
 //Unless there are more capitals in the item name
 //Just put the grade index in the => value.
 $exceptions= array(
        'Magic Plate Armor'=>'legendary',
        'Avenger'=>'legendary',
        'Golden helmet'=>'epic',
        'Yalahari armor'=>'legendary',
        'Dragon scale legs'=>'legendary',
        'Golden boots'=>'epic',
        'Backpack of holding'=>'rare',
        'Demonwing axe'=>'legendary',
        'Solar axe'=>'legendary',
        'Hellforged axe'=>'legendary'
                    );
?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @author Soulreaper
 * @copyright 2010
 * Functions for EQShower
 */

class EQShower {
    function item_info($val,$attributes)
    {
        $EQShower=new EQShower;
        $cl=$EQShower->item_grade($attributes,$val[0]);

        empty($val[1])?$desc_str="":$desc_str="<br /><br />".$val[1];
        empty($val[2])?$arm_str="":$arm_str="Armor: ".$val[2]."<br />";
        empty($val[4])?$size_str="":$size_str="Size: ".$val[4]." slots";
        empty($val[5])?$att_str="":$att_str="Attack: ".$val[5]."<br />";
        empty($val[6])?$sp_str="":$sp_str="Speed: + ".$val[6]."<br />";
        empty($val[13])?$def_a="":$def_a="+ ".$val[13];
        empty($val[7])?$def_str="":$def_str="Defense: ".$val[7]." $def_a<br />";
        if(!empty($val[8])){$el_str="Fire: ".$val[8]."<br />";}
        if(!empty($val[9])){$el_str="Ice: ".$val[9]."<br />";}
        if(!empty($val[10])){$el_str="Earth: ".$val[10]."<br />";}
        if(!empty($val[11])){$el_str="Energy: ".$val[11]."<br />";}
        empty($val[12])?$ran_str="":$ran_str="Range: ".$val[12]."<br />";
        empty($val[14])?$sk_sh="":$sk_sh="Shielding: + ".$val[14]."<br />";
        empty($val[15])?$sk_mag="":$sk_mag="Magic: + ".$val[15]."<br />"; 
        empty($val[16])?$eb_all="":$eb_all="Protection All: ".$val[16]."%<br />"; 
        empty($val[17])?$charg_str="":$charg_str="Charges: ".$val[17]."<br />";
        empty($val[18])?$sk_dist="":$sk_dist="Distance: + ".$val[18]."<br />"; 
        empty($val[19])?$eb_fire="":$eb_fire="Protection fire: ".$val[19]."%<br />"; 
        empty($val[20])?$eb_earth="":$eb_earth="Protection earth: ".$val[20]."%<br />"; 
        empty($val[21])?$eb_ice="":$eb_ice="Protection ice: ".$val[21]."%<br />"; 
        empty($val[22])?$eb_ene="":$eb_ene="Protection energy: ".$val[22]."%<br />";   
        empty($val[23])?$eb_dth="":$eb_dth="Protection death: ".$val[23]."%<br />"; 
        empty($val[24])?$eb_hol="":$eb_hol="Protection holy: ".$val[24]."%<br />"; 
        empty($val[25])?$eb_pys="":$eb_pys="Protection physical: ".$val[25]."%<br />"; 
        empty($val[26])?$sk_axe="":$sk_axe="Axe: + ".$val[26]."<br />";
        empty($val[27])?$sk_club="":$sk_club="Club: + ".$val[27]."<br />";
        empty($val[28])?$sk_sword="":$sk_sword="Sword: + ".$val[28]."<br />";
        empty($val[29])?$dura="":$dura="Duration: ".$val[29]." minutes.<br />";
        empty($val[30])?$sk_fist="":$sk_fist="Fist: + ".$val[30]."<br />";
        empty($val[31])?$eb_mana="":$eb_mana="Protection manadrain: ".$val[31]."%<br />"; 
        empty($val[32])?$eb_life="":$eb_life="Protection lifedrain: ".$val[32]."%<br />";
        empty($val[33])?$eb_drop="":$eb_drop="Protection drop: ".$val[33]."%<br />";
        empty($val[34])?$hit_ch="":$hit_ch="Hit chance: ".$val[34]."%<br />";
        empty($val[35])?$sh_type="":$sh_type="Element: ".$val[35]."<br />";

        if(empty($val[8]) AND empty($val[9]) AND empty($val[10]) AND empty($val[11])){$ele_str="";}

        $str="<div class=\'$cl\'>".$val[0]."</div><font class=\'attr\'>$arm_str $sp_str $sh_type $att_str $ran_str $def_str $hit_ch $sk_sh $sk_sword $sk_axe $sk_club $sk_fist $sk_mag $sk_dist $eb_all $eb_drop $eb_mana $eb_life $eb_fire $eb_earth $eb_ice $eb_ene $eb_dth $eb_hol $eb_pys $el_str $charg_str $dura Weight: ".$val[3]." oz $desc_str</font>";
        return $str;
    }

    function item_grade($attributes,$name)
    {
        require('config.php');

        if(!array_key_exists($name,$exceptions)){
            if($attributes<=$config['normal']['attributes']){return $config['class']['normal'];}
            if($attributes==$config['rare']['attributes']){return $config['class']['rare'];}
            if($attributes==$config['epic']['attributes']){return $config['class']['epic'];}
            if($attributes>=$config['legendary']['attributes']){return $config['class']['legendary'];}
        }else{
            return $config['class'][$exceptions[$name]];
        }
    }

    function table_exists ($table, $db) 
    { 
     $tables = mysql_list_tables ($db); 
       while (list ($temp) = mysql_fetch_array ($tables)) 
        {
          if ($temp == $table) 
            {
               return TRUE;
            }
       }
     return FALSE;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Esse sublinhado é um link?

Comment: Seria bom tb postar o HTML dessa parte onde está sublinhado, já facilitaria bastante uma resposta.

Comment: @Dvdsamm não é um link, pra tirar a duvida entre nesse link http://www.royalbaiak.com/?subtopic=characters&name=Teste

Comment: @Dvdsamm o html é muito grande, mais posso postar sim

Comment: @Dvdsamm Editei o Topico

Comment: Vai no arquivo "tooltip.php" e altere a linha `.lege {color:#ff8f00;font-weight:bold;font-size:12pt;text-decoration:underline;padding-bottom:6px;}` para `.lege {color:#ff8f00;font-weight:bold;font-size:12pt;padding-bottom:6px;}` e veja se dá certo.

Comment: Cara funcinou, muito obrigado

Comment: Vou postar como resposta. Abs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acesse o arquivo "tooltip.php" e altere a linha do CSS:

```
.lege {color:#ff8f00;font-weight:bold;font-size:12pt;text-decorati‌​on:underline;padding‌​-bottom:6px;}
```

Para (*retirando o* `text-decorati‌​on:underline`):

```
.lege {color:#ff8f00;font-weight:bold;font-size:12pt;padding-botto‌​m:6px;}
```

Não é necessário colocar `<b></b>` porque a classe já é em negrito (`font-weight: bold`).

Comment: Muito Obrigado!